# Any better terms or words for an overseas office?

Tags: synonyms

Is there any better term or word for an overseas office? It's like a company opening a new workplace in other countries.

Comment: These are sometimes called *satellite offices* (because they orbit around HQ), or in certain industries *branch offices* or just *branches*. Your term, *overseas office*, however, carries the dentition that the office is in another county explicitly. Mine do not. They simply mean subordinate office; they can be in the same country as Hq, but e.g. in a different state or area.

Comment: Unclear:  Is this a sales office or such, to extend the reach of the company, or an outsourcing site, to employ cheap overseas labor?

Comment: The phrase "oversea office" puts me in mind of an oil rig or fantastical flying fortress suspended over crashing waves. The phrase you'd probably want to use is "overseas office", which implies that ocean(s) separate the office from its headquarters.

Comment: Why not 'foreign office'?

Comment: This question reminds me of the phrase my wife's company uses for its cheap offshoring site for cheap labour in India: it's known as the Global Talent Centre.

Answer (score 1):

**Foreign branch/subsidiary/affiliate** may fit.

Answer (score 0):

A term that would work would be Offshore company (Or office)

Offshore Company:

> Firm registered or incorporated outside the country where it has its main offices and operations, or where its principal investors reside.

Comment: Certainly in the UK, an 'offshore office' would imply that it's on an island [that's even smaller than the British Isles].  We wouldn't, for example, call the New York office of a British company 'offshore'.  We *would* use 'offshore' if it was on the Isle of Man [small island, outside the UK's jurisdiction.]

Comment: *Offshoring* is relocation, not simply opening a foreign branch. *Offshore* furthermore carries negative connotations among the ,public as it is commonly done to skirt taxes, wages, or regulations.